# Spinner button that starts spinning when function is called and stops when it ends

Tags: javascript, spinner

I'm trying to make a spinner button that will spin while I make an AJAX request and stop when the answer is received.

I've got the AJAX handled but the spinning doesn't seem to work with the following code:

```
function refresh (id){
    var iconElem = document.getElementById("spinner" + id);
    iconElem.classList.add('fa-spin');
    sleep(5000);
    var buttonRefresh = document.getElementById("refreshButton" + id); 
    buttonRefresh.classList.remove("fa-spin");

};
```

Note : I have replaced the ajax function with a sleep (implemented elsewhere, but it works like like it should) since I am in a non-php environment.

What happens here is that the the class "fa-spin" is being added while the sleep is over, even though it comes after in the code... Am I missing some kind of "refresh" that I need to execute in order to make the added class effective ?

Comment: Hard to tell from your code, but it looks like you need to come to terms with the asynchronous nature of AJAX.

Comment: It would be nice if you could share how you are doing the call.

Comment: This is wrong approach. AJAX is asynchronous despite code 'order'. You should read up on AJAX callbacks and remove the spinner class in the callback function.

Comment: Have you tried using the call back or Success block of ajax ?

Comment: Got it, I will have the class being removed by the callback function, thanks for the heads up, but why is my current code not working ? (there is no ajax whatsoever, just a plain sleep)

Comment: From the code you gave, you are calling adding `fa-spin` on a different element than you are removing `fa-spin` from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the spinning in the completion callback of the ajax call as it is a async call.
What you are doing here is starting and then immediately stopping the spinner before the ajax call even finishes.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
   // stop the spinner here
  }
});
```

Comment: How did you conclude that the ajax is async?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but why is my function not working correctly right now ? There is no AJAX going on (yet) since I replaced it with a sleep.

Comment: Sleep is an async functionality itself.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that one coming, that explains it... thank you !

Comment: @SrimoyeeSen sleep might be calling a synced ajax request, and then op's code would be okay (using `async:false` header)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest solution with a callback:

```
function sleep(callback,timeout){
  setTimeout(callback,timeout)
}

sleep(() => {
  //stop spinner here
},200)
```

Anyways, I suggest you to read more [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff)

If you are doing an ajax request, you can also use the `async:false` header to make your request synced, and then your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to the style or content of the document become effective only when the JavaScript function finishes and returns to the main event loop. Therefore, assuming your `sleep()` function works as expected (by doing a busy wait or something like that, although that is not actually *sleeping*), you can only see the total effect of all changes when the function returns. If you follow the advice of the other answers and remove the style in the callback of the AJAX call, you will be fine.

Comment: Ok that's the actual information I was looking for, thank you! I will follow the advice from the other answers as to fix, but this actually explains what was going on with my current script.